# Sitecore dictionary items Editable via page editor

Tags: sitecore

I am trying to implement Sitecore Dictionary items to be edited via PageEditor.

This is my approach.. Just need your thoughts and suggestions.

To make it simple and not to mess up with the pipelines, here is a simple way of what I am doing.

Normally you do a sitecore translate for example,

> @Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text("SomeKey")

You can encapsulate the Translate to a custom class which might look like

```
public static class CustomTranslate 
{ 
 public static string Text(string key) 
{
if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditorEditing) 
{ 
string val = String.Empty; 
Item currentItem = Context.Database.GetItem(ResourcesController.ItemLookUp()[key]); 

if (currentItem != null) 
{ 
val = FieldRenderer.Render(currentItem, "Phrase"); 
} 
return val; 
} 
else 
return Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text(key); 
} 
}
```

The CustomTranslate.Text returns a FieldRenderer in PageEdit mode else returns the Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text

Then in your code you can refer the translations as

> @CustomTranslate.Text("SomeKey")

The Lookup can be a dictionary of Key and Item ID as shown in below code,

```
public static class ResourceController 
{ 

public static Dictionary ItemLookUp() 
{ 

///get dictionary path..etc.. code not included 

//read all sitecore dictionary Items
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item[] items = 
Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems("fast:" + dictionaryPath + 


 "//*[@@templateid='{6D1CD897-1936-4A3A-A511-289A94C2A7B1}']"); 

//build a Dictionary<string,string> using sitecore item key and Guid.
items.All(y => { resourceDictionary.Add(y["Key"], y.ID.Guid.ToString()); return true;} 

//    Key,Guid dictionary
    return resourceDictionary; 

    } 
    }
```

A Simpler and much easier approach ! Thoughts, Comments ?

Comment: Just saw this posted today - http://jockstothecore.com/editable-dictionary-items/. This may help.

Comment: Thanks. Saw the post.. needs some considerable time and testing.